# How to stash in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: git-stash, visual-studio-2022

There is no way to use git stash here, except apply and pop

[image: There is no way to use git stash here]

Comment: @Brett How do we stash the changes compared to Visual Studio 2022? Only from the console like git stash --include-untracked?

Answer (score 98):

It's in the dropdown menu on the commit. Click the dropdown arrow next to "Commit All".

Click either:

"Stash All (--include-untracked)

OR

"Stash All and Keep Staged (--keep-index)

[image]

Comment: Stash Well hidden.

Comment: too well hidden

Comment: Very hidden, been looking for this for ages.

Comment: Just for info: If your solution contains projects that each have their own git repository, then there is no dropdown next to the commit button. You have to select only a single repository in the top dropdown menu ontop of the commit message input field inside the Git Changes window, then the dropdown menu on the commit button is visible including the stash menu item.

Comment: what if i dont want to stash all?
i just want to select say one or two files and stash those while keeping the rest of my files intact?

Comment: I agree. There should be a separate Stash button to the left the Commit button. And I'm trying to figure out what the two stash options actually do!

Comment: If someone works at Microsoft please just show better this button...